# Как вернуться в начало?

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Отменить" меня возвращало на стартовую страницу выбора файла, но как это сделать вообще? переструктурировать весь код?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from rembg import remove
import os
import sys



window = Tk()

window.geometry('700x500')
window.title("ext")
window.configure(bg='#212121')
window.resizable (width=False, height=False)


def choose_file():
    filetypes = ("Изображение", "*.jpg *.png"),

    global filename 
    global basename

    filename = fd.askopenfilename(title="Открыть файл", initialdir="/",
                                      filetypes=filetypes)
    input_path = (filename)
    basename = os.path.basename(filename)
    fixed_width = 450
    new_res = Image.open(input_path)
    width_percent = (fixed_width / float(new_res.size[0]))
    height_size = int((float(new_res.size[1]) * float(width_percent)))
    sh_res = new_res.resize((fixed_width, height_size))

    global canvas_1

    canvas_1 = Canvas(
    window,
    bg='#212121',
    width = 450, 
    height = 350,
    highlightthickness=0
    )      
    canvas_1.pack()      
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(sh_res)      
    canvas_1.create_image(
    0,
    0, 
    anchor=NW, 
    image=img
    ) 
    canvas_1.place(relx=0.20, rely=0.02, anchor=NW) 
    
    global btn_obr

    btn_obr = tk.Button(window,text="Обработать",
                     command=backre_file,
                     width = 20,
                     height = 3,
                     anchor=CENTER,
                     bg='#2F353B',
                     fg='white',
                     borderwidth=0,
                     font='helv39'
                     )
    btn_obr.grid(column=0, row=1)
    btn_obr.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.85, anchor=CENTER)

    global btn_cancel

    btn_cancel = tk.Button(window,text="Отменить",
                     command=(cancel),
                     width = 20,
                     height = 3,
                     anchor=CENTER,
                     bg='#2F353B',
                     fg='white',
                     borderwidth=0,
                     font='helv39'
                     )
    btn_cancel.grid(column=0, row=1)
    btn_cancel.place(relx=0.70, rely=0.85, anchor=CENTER)

    print(btn_cancel)
    
    canvas_1.mainloop() 



def backre_file():
     input = Image.open(filename)
     global removebg 
     removebg = remove(input)
     removebg.save('C:/Users/Nochka/Desktop/Ph/removebg.png', 'PNG')
     fixed_width = 450
     new_res = Image.open('C:/Users/Nochka/Desktop/Ph/removebg.png')
     width_percent = (fixed_width / float(new_res.size[0]))
     height_size = int((float(new_res.size[1]) * float(width_percent)))
     sh_res = new_res.resize((fixed_width, height_size))
     canvas = Canvas(
     window,
     bg='#212121',
     width = 450, 
     height = 350,
     highlightthickness=0
     )      
     canvas.pack()      
     img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(sh_res)      
     canvas.create_image(
     0,
     0, 
     anchor=NW, 
     image=img
     ) 
     canvas.place(relx=0.20, rely=0.02, anchor=NW) 
     

     btn_save = tk.Button(window,text="Сохранить",
                     command=(save_file),
                     width = 20,
                     height = 3,
                     anchor=CENTER,
                     bg='#2F353B',
                     fg='white',
                     borderwidth=0,
                     font='helv39'
                     )
     btn_save.grid(column=0, row=1)
     btn_save.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.85, anchor=CENTER)

     

     canvas.mainloop()


def save_file():
     filetypes = ("Изображение", "*.jpg *.png"),

     global s_file

     s_file = fd.asksaveasfilename(title="Сохранить Файл",defaultextension="png", initialfile="basename", initialdir="/",
                                      filetypes=filetypes)
     print(s_file)
     removebg.save(s_file)



btn_file = tk.Button(window,text="Выбрать файл",
                     command=choose_file,
                     width = 40,
                     height =10,
                     anchor=CENTER)
btn_file.grid(column=0, row=1)
btn_file.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)


def cancel():
     btn_obr.destroy()
     btn_cancel.destroy()
     canvas_1.quit()
     print(btn_cancel)
     btn_file.destroy()

     btn_file2 = tk.Button(window,text="Выбрать файл",
                     command=choose_file,
                     width = 40,
                     height =10,
                     anchor=CENTER)
     btn_file2.grid(column=0, row=1)
     btn_file2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Делайте отображение "страницы" выбора файла. Условно, выбор файла должен вызываться из функции, когда его нужно вызвать - вызываете. При этом в ней не должно быть кода создания и запуска самого приложения.